# Send key not working for custom application in Auto It

Tags: automation, ui-automation, autoit

I want to open my application myprogram.exe and hit tab. I have written the following script

```
Local $Pid = ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\myProgram.exe","-a arg","","")
Sleep(5000)
Send("{TAB}")
```

But it doesn't work. My application gets open and it works if I manually hit TAB. But it's not accepting any key via the script.

I tried the same thing with notepad and it works without any problem

```
Local $Pid = ShellExecute("notepad.exe","","","")
Sleep(5000)
Send("{TAB}")
```

Comment: Try to use Controlsend or ControlClick instead.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the window has focus with `WinActivate`

Also as suggested try controlsend or controlclick, if ether of those doesn't work it is properly because the program you are trying to access doesn't take simulated inputs